# Type hint the methods of a parent class

Tags: python

My parent class inherits `list` and adds a few methods which return items in this list. My child class is a sequence of objects (all of the same type). How do I type hint the child (`Inventory`) class to tell a type checker (e.g. PyCharm) that the filter method returns a sequence of `Car` objects?

I rewrote an excerpt of my code below. Hopefully I didn't oversimplify this example.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


class DB(list):
    def filter(self, **kwargs):
        """Returns all matching items in the DB.
        Args:
            **kwargs: Attribute/Value pairs.
        """

        def is_match(item):
            """Do all the attribute/value pairs match for this item?"""
            result = all(getattr(item, k) == v
                         for k, v in kwargs.items())
            return result

        return type(self)(x for x in self if is_match(x))


@dataclass
class Car:
    make: str = 'Tesla'


class Inventory(DB[Car]):
    # Type hint the Inventory class as a sequence of Car objects?
    pass

    # Type hint the parent filter() method???
    filter : (make: str) -> Inventory[Inventory]



inventory = Inventory((Car(), Car('Jaguar')))
inventory[0].make               # Autocomplete is working here.                    
filtered = inventory.filter(model='X')
filtered[0].?                   # Pycharm should know that this is a Car, and autocomplete attributes.
```

EDITED: -> Inventory[Inventory] and formatting.

tl;dr: How to type hint a class method outside of the class.

Comment: Do you have access to the `DB` class? I.e. can you change the code that defines it?

Comment: @Roy Cohen: Yes

Comment: Then write something like `T = typing.TypeVar('T'); class DB(list[T]): ...` (I don't know a lot about python type hints so that might not work but give it a try).

Comment: @RoyCohen: Wow, it works! Amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `DB` needs to be generic for this to work so instead of:

```py
class DB(list): ...
```

It should be:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class DB(list[T]): ...
```

**Edit:**
In python 3.5 - 3.8 you can't do `list[T]` so you would do:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List

T = TypeVar('T')
class DB(List[T]): ...
```

thanks @ChaimG for the suggestion.

Comment: This works as is in Python 3.9. For Python 3.5 - 3.8 use `typing.List[T]` instead of `list[T]`.

Comment: @ChaimG Would that require subclassing from `list` indepandently? E.g. `class DB(typing.List[T], list): ...`